# How do I get Upstart to start my Mediatomb service?

Tags: upstart, init, init.d, services, mediatomb

I've been struggling, trying to get my Mediatomb server to start automatically on Upstart run level 2.  I can't figure it out.  I guess Upstart is still new to me and I don't understand it.  I even [read the whole manual](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-specific) and it is vague and never mentions any of the inner workings of how things work.

I can obviously run mediatomb with this command and so getting it to run is not my question:

```
sudo mediatomb --config /etc/mediatomb/config.xml
```

or

```
mediatomb --config ~/.mediatomb/config.xml
```

I know Upstart supposedly will start services as superuser but what happens when running Upstart commands as a normal user?  Do priviledges get escalated?  I can't seem to figure it out.

These commands don't work:

```
service mediatomb start
/etc/init.d/mediatomb start 
sudo initctl start mediatomb (says it started but not really)
```

To me, this all seems to be some kind of permissions issue but I don't understand enough about Upstart to figure this out.  Very frustrating.

```
me@linux:/etc/init$ start mediatomb
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.58"
(uid=1000 pid=2665 comm="start mediatomb ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job"
member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0"
destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installed system using Xubuntu.  This time Mediatomb autostarts but the port 47152 is only visble on localhost.  The service can also be restarted using `sudo service mediatomb start`.  My external media device cannot see mediatomb.

I learned:

> 1. Mediatomb puts the db in the /var/lib/mediatomb.db , owned by the mediatomb user
> 2. The config.xml is owned by root in /etc/mediatomb/config.xml
> 3. The web files are at /usr/share/mediatomb  and owned by root.
> 4. The /etc/init directory contains the Upstart script and I made no modifications to it.
> 5. The /etc/init.d directory contains the old, unused init script.
> 6. The media disk I am sharing is auto-mounted by root and has 777 permissions.

At this point I think this may be related to the fact that my Xubuntu is a 64-bit system and that, for some reason the listener binds to localhost rather than my external IP?

---

UPDATE: finally figured out that it was a misconfiguration in my config.xml that caused the server to think there wasn't any files to serve.   My library is all .avi files and I had the .avi profile misconfigured in the config.xml and so it couldn't render anything.